# Magento - Select an option on product page will not refresh

Tags: magento

I may be missing something but we show our SKU and Weights of items on the "Additional Information" tab. When setting up configurable items we will set a unique sku to the associated product. When a customer selects "Large" for example the sku that is shown is the original sku and not the updated sku. Same with weight. Being there is no weight on the configurable product and weight is only applied to the associated product, when the customer selects their option it is not refreshing the additional information to the custom attributes.

any thoughts on how to have the product view refresh when selecting an option from a drop down choice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Magento does not do this by default. The only time I've seen configurable options update values on the page dynamically is when the configurable option increases the price.

If you feel like driving yourself nuts with Prototype, check the template at `/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` - Product.Config() handles updating the price. If you prefer your sanity, do some jQuery voodoo and update those values yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I found a work around by placing a new attribute called "Displayed Weight" this will allow it to show on the configurable items. I was just hoping for a missed check box or something for refreshing.